# Calculate simple math equation

Tags: swift

I try to use swift code to calculate 10 * 75% = 7.5

```
var b : Int = 10
var a : Int = 75
// result x is 0
var x = b * (a / 100)
```

However the result is zero. How to get 7.5 result without changing the type and value of `a` and `b`?

UPDATE:

I got it right by:

```
 var x: Double = (Double(b) * (Double(a) / 100)) // x is 7.5
```

Now, how can I round it to 8 as a `Int` type?

Comment: But I didn't claim x is an integer type. I expected swift is smart to assign the right type to x

Comment: Swift did assign the right type to x, an `Int` divided by an `Int` is an `Int`

Comment: Swift is smart enough. You are doing `Int` math so `x` is an `Int`.

Comment: BTW - your use of `: Int` for `a` and `b` is redundant. `var b = 10` will automatically make `b` the type `Int`.

Comment: I updated my question now. Thanks.

Comment: Not being serious, but this fulfills the requirements: `var x = b * a / 100; if (b * a % 100) >= 50 { x += 1 }` 

Comment: It is simple. In the same way you converted a and b to Double, convert x to an int with ` print(Int(x)) `

Answer (score 0):

You're using integer (i.e. whole number) arithmetic, when what you want is floating-point arithmetic. Change one of the types to `Float`, and Swift will figure out that `x` is also a `Float`.

```
var b : Int = 10
var a : Int = 75
var x = Float(b) * (Float(a) / 100.0) // now x is a Float (.75)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok then you just need to do:

```
var b : Int = 10
let c = (Double(b) * 0.75)
let restult = ceil(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

For doing arithmetic in Swift, both sides of the equation must be using the same type. Try using this code:

```
let b = 10.0
let a = 75.0
let x = b * (a / 100.0
print(x)
```

> 7.5

To make it round up, use the built in ceil function

```
print(ceil(x))
```

> 8.0